# The reverse pull-* - Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-4

does not work pull-right or pull-left, what do I do wrong?

The code itself

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <section class="col-sm-9 pull-right" style="background: olive;">
      <article>content</article>
    </section>

    <section class="col-sm-3 pull-left" style="background: #008040;">
      <aside>Widgets</aside>
    </section>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no `pull-right` and `pull-left` in Bootstrap 4.
It doesn't use `float` anymore, it uses flex.

You have two divs and you're trying to change their order by using float, you can simply invert their position in the HTML:

```
<section class="col-sm-3" style="background: #008040;">
    <aside>Widgets</aside>
</section>
<section class="col-sm-9" style="background: olive;">
    <article>content</article>
</section>
```

If you want to keep their positions in the HTML and invert them anyway, you can use flex-order:

```
<section class="col-sm-3 order-1" style="background: #008040;">
    <aside>Widgets</aside>
</section>
<section class="col-sm-9 order-0" style="background: olive;">
    <article>content</article>
</section>
```

Doc: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/